# Configuring circuit breaker with service activator

Tags: java, spring-integration, apache-kafka

Configuration details :

```
  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="toKafka"/>

  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="sendMessageToKafkaChannel"/>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="toKafka" output-channel="sendMessageToKafkaChannel" order="1" ref="conditionalProducerService" method="producerCircuitBreaker">
       <int:request-handler-advice-chain> 
              <ref bean="circuitBreakerAdvice" />
       </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
  </int:service-activator>

  <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="producerContext"
                                                                       auto-startup="true" channel="toKafka" message-key="kafka_messageKey"/>

  <bean id="circuitBreakerAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
    <property name="threshold" value="2"/>                      
    <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="15000" />                     
  </bean>
```

---

```
  public Message<?> producerCircuitBreaker(Message<?> payload) {
      throw  new RuntimeException("foo Pro");
  }
```

---

```
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          toKafka.send(MessageBuilder
                              .withPayload(messageVO.getMessageContentVO())                                  
                              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topic)
                              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID,Integer.parseInt(messageVO.getPartition())).
                              build());

                 APPLOGGER.info("sending message");
   }
```

Expecting to get the process to fail 2 times with exception and then "circuit breaker open" exception but it is simply stopping after throwing the below exception in the console.

Also how can we configure error-channel here.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67aae50e548c78470cd0

**updated config:**

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="toKafka"  ref="gw">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain> <ref bean="circuitBreakerAdvice"/>
                      </int:request-handler-advice-chain> 
   </int:service-activator>

   <int:channel id="failedChannel1" />


   <int:gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toKafka" default-reply-timeout="0" error-channel="failedChannel1"  />

     <int:chain input-channel="failedChannel1">
        <int:transformer expression="'failed:'+payload.failedMessage.payload+ ' with a' +payload.cause.message" />
        <int-stream:stderr-channel-adapter append-newline="true"/>
            </int:chain>
```

getting below exception.
**failed:TestVo[data=sample message]] with Cannot process message.**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/921be7691c41d125dc84
**however it is working with same message otherwise.**(message content changed intentionally)

Also tried  putting invalid value for the producer context: eg. broker-   list/value-class-type as invalid class type than expected as below.

getting below error but expecting to get CB to come into picture and message should flow to the error channel.

in case of value-class-type : CB not invoked however message flowing to the error channel but there are many message are coming for 1 message published.

**failed:TestVo [data={tes message}}] with  No converter found capable of converting from type xx.xxx.vo.TestVo to type java.lang.String**

these is occuring in the console many times.

in case of broker-list : it is simply throwing exception in the console.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ece517fb5e82ac73492

**Expected** : CB to get invoked and message flow to the error channel in all cases.

```
  <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="producerContext"
                                                                       auto-startup="true" channel="toKafka" message-key="kafka_messageKey"/>  

  <int-kafka:producer-context id="producerContext" producer-properties="producerProperties">
                                                            <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
                                                                           <int-kafka:producer-configuration
                                                                                            broker-list="1.2.3:9092" topic="headers['topic']" key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                                                                            value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                                                                            value-encoder="kafkaEncoder" key-encoder="kafkaKeyEncoder"
                                                                                            compression-type="none" />
                                                            </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
                                            </int-kafka:producer-context>
```

Answer (score 3):

With that code, you need `try {...}` around the `send()`.

The first two attempts will catch your `RuntimeException`; the next will catch the circuit breaker exception.

Use a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) with an error channel instead of sending to the channel directly.

**EDIT**

This code...

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="toKafka"  ref="gw">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain> <ref bean="circuitBreakerAdvice"/>
                  </int:request-handler-advice-chain> 
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toKafka" default-reply-timeout="0" error-channel="failedChannel1"  />
```

When you send a message to `toKafka`, the gateway will be invoked which will send the message to `toKafka` in a loop.

It will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,it is working with try/catch block.
But now I have updated the configuration as suggested with gateway and would like to invoke CB for connection timed out /invalid broker details etc and other environment related issue.facing some issue.
Updated config in original post.Please suggest.

Comment: We need to see the full stack trace for the second condition - just the error message is not enough.

Comment: already added above the 2 links for error message,adding it again here,thanks:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/921be7691c41d125dc84  


https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ece517fb5e82ac73492

Comment: The second one only has an error message, not the stack trace - your transformer is suppressing the stack trace. However, your problem is that the circuit breaker is not kicking in because your error flow is suppressing the exception - it simply logs the error. You either need to remove the error flow or have it re-throw the message payload after you logged it.

Comment: Hi @Gary,thanks for above suggestion.it is helpful.

but still struggling with 1st one.
failed:TestVo[data=sample message]] with Cannot process message.

same message structure is working fine without the gateway earlier.
pls find the link with full stack trace. Any suggestion would be great.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ec62c1682dea5ce543ee

Comment: That stacktrace is incomplete - there is no `cause` see the disjoint between lines 798 and 799.

Comment: Hi Gary,

Pls find below the stack trace.not sure if it can be helpful.

https://gist.github.com/sum1220/3d9e0405a7487bb9a4c5



Tried debugging but unable to put debug point particularly in this  method from where the exception is thrown.


org.springframework.integration.util. MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal()
 .....

throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot process message", evaluationException);

Comment: Again; there is no stack trace in that log. Remove your transformer and stderr channel adapter and replace it with a `<int:logging-channel-adapter/>` so we see the full stack trace.